# How to integrate react-intl-tel-input-v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-hooks, web-deployment

While using react-intl-tel-input-v2 I was getting this error:-`× TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'e')` I have install the react-intl-tel-input-v2 from npm Try many things but nothing work if anyone know the solution please help Even if you know any other npm package which help me please suggest

I was getting the error in this part:-
 `handleChange = (e) => { const { name, value } = e.target this.setState({ [name]: value`

This is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import firebase from './firebase'
import 'firebase/auth';
import "./App.css";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";
// import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'
// import $ from 'jquery';
// import intlTelInputUtils from 'jquery';
import ReactIntlTelInput from 'react-intl-tel-input-v2';
import 'intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css';


class Login extends React.Component {

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
      
    })
    this.setState({ phoneNumber: value }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.phoneNumber);
    });
  }
  configureCaptcha = () =>{
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('sign-in-button', {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response) => {

        // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.

        this.onSignInSubmit();
        console.log("Recaptca varified")
      },
       defaultCountry: "IN"
     }
    );
  }
  onSignInSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.configureCaptcha()
    const phoneNumber = this.state.mobile
    console.log(phoneNumber)
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    get(child(dbRef, `Users/${phoneNumber}`)).then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)

          .then((confirmationResult) => {

            // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
            // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).

            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;

            alert('An OTP has been sent to your registered mobile number')
            localStorage.setItem("Phone_No", phoneNumber)
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('Phone_No'));


          }).catch((error) => {

            console.error(error);
            alert("Oops! Some error occured. Please try again.")
          });
      }
      else {
        alert('Sorry, this mobile number is not registered with us. Please use your registered mobile number.');
      }

    })
  }
  onSubmitOTP = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const code = this.state.otp
    console.log(code)
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(code).then((result) => {
      // User signed in successfully.
      const Users = result.user;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Users))
      this.props.history.push("/home");
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert("You have entered wrong code")
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main-header">
        <img src="./55k-logo.png" alt="Company Logo" style={{ height: "80px", width: "200px" }} />
        <br />
        <div>
          <h2>Login Form</h2>
          <p>Limtless Water. From Unlimited Air.</p>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSignInSubmit}>
            <div id="sign-in-button"></div>
            {/* <PhoneInput */}

            <label>Mobile Number</label> <br />
            {/* for="phoneNumber"  */}

            <ReactIntlTelInput
          type="tel" id="phone"  name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange}
           value={this.state.value}
          // onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
            {/* <input type="tel" id="phone" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter Your Number" required onChange={this.handleChange} /> */}
            <div className="buttons">
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitOTP}>
            <label >Code</label> <br />
            {/* for="code" */}

            <input type="number" name="otp" placeholder="Enter The 6 Digit OTP" required onChange={this.handleChange} />
            <div className="buttons" >
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: first you need to know what is `e` holding. try to add first line console.log(e)

Comment: it hold the input which i give in the filed of phone number like this:- SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input#phone, …}
Login.js:47 +
Login.js:40 SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input#phone, …}
Login.js:47 +9
Login.js:40 SyntheticBaseEvent {_reactName: 'onChange', _targetInst: null, type: 'change', nativeEvent: InputEvent, target: input#phone, …}
Login.js:47 +91